# Removing the Multiples of Decrease and Increase in a Spike

Tags: smoothing, averaging

I have a signal shown below. I got this signal from a glove, where I want to detect the movement of a finger. What I am planning to do is to threshold the signal, so I can get a binary signal indicates the presence of the spike. My problem is that I have multiple increase and decrease within a single spike. So, using threshold technique will produce a "fluctuation" of zeros and ones for each spike. This means that the finger was moved multiple times within that time interval, which is uncorrect.I tried using statistical measures to solve this problem, and I also tried to get the envelop of the signal. However, none of them was able to remove those increases and decreases. What do you suggest to solve this problem [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a moving average filter followed by your threshold detector. You can change the span of your moving average filter based on the time length in which you want multiple spikes to be combined.